# Why was Iago hiding in Jafar's 'Old Man' disguise?

Tags: disney, aladdin-1992

When Jafar meets Aladdin in prison to fetch the lamp, he disguises himself as an old man. For some reason, he has his parrot Iago hidden in his back while in disguise.

> **OLD MAN**: There is a cave, boy.  A cave of wonders.  Filled
>           with treasures beyond your wildest dreams.
>           Treasure enough to impress even your princess, I'd
>           wager.
>
> (*The OLD MAN turns his back, and IAGO sticks
>       his head out of JAFAR's "old man" disguise.*)
>
> **IAGO**: Jafar, can ya hurry it up?  I'm dyin' in here!

Why was Iago hiding in Jafar's back? Why not just have him wait outside?

[image: Iago hiding in Jafar's back]

Comment: I can’t tell from this still: Is the old man meant to have a hunched back?

Comment: @Ryan, yep, you've got it - [Iago was part of the disguise](http://animal-villains.wikia.com/wiki/Iago).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jafar is disguising himself as a hunchbacked man:

[image: The "old man" has a hunchback.]

But Jafar's own back is perfectly straight:

[image: Jafar is not a hunchback]

Iago is hiding inside the "old man's" tattered robe to create the illusion of a hunch, adding to the verisimilitude of the disguise.

Comment: You have my +1 for correctly using the word verisimilitude. I would have also accepted efficacy or believableness. Oh, and the answer isn't bad either.